# Choose where org-agenda-tree-to-indirect-buffer window opens

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, window-splitting

If I have an org file open:

```
 +----------------------------------------+
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 |                org file                |
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 |                                        |
 +----------------------------------------+
```

And open the Agenda view:

```
 +----------------------------------------+
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |    org file      |       agenda        |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 +------------------+---------------------+
```

And then hit TAB on a todo item, it does `(org-agenda-goto)` and jumps to the item in the original window:

```
 +----------------------------------------+
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |    org file      |       agenda        |
 |    jumped to     |                     |
 |    item          |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 +------------------+---------------------+
```

Which is great.  If I do `(org-agenda-tree-to-indirect-buffer)`, however, it opens in a teeny window below the agenda:

```
 +----------------------------------------+
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |    org file      |       agenda        |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  +---------------------+
 |                  |     org item i.b.   |
 +------------------+---------------------+
```

What I'd like to happen is:

```
 +----------------------------------------+
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |    org item i.b. |       agenda        |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 |                  |                     |
 +------------------+---------------------+
```

I *could* do this by just typing `TAB , s b`, which isn't so bad, but out of general interest I'm wondering how do I control the placement of the new window that `org-agenda-tree-to-indirect-buffer` creates?

Comment: If you set `org-indirect-buffer-display` to `'current-window`, does that achieve the desired behavior?  `(setq org-indirect-buffer-display 'current-window)`  The default value is `'other-window`.  To see available choices, type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable` ....

Comment: Thanks - that doesn't work unfortunately.  Oddly, both `'current-window` and `'other-window` open the indirect buffer in the same place for me.  (I checked and the variable is being updated OK - e.g. if I use `'new-frame` the indirect buffer appears in a new frame).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this request.  Here's a workaround:

In org-agenda.el I found the function: org-agenda-tree-to-indirect-buffer
and changed the line which calls "split-window".

I added the parameters `nil 't` to the `split-window` call:

Before:

```
 (unwind-protect
        (unless (and indirect-window (window-live-p indirect-window))
          (setq indirect-window (split-window agenda-window)))
```

After:

```
(unwind-protect
        (unless (and indirect-window (window-live-p indirect-window))
          (setq indirect-window (split-window agenda-window nil 't)))
```

It's a hack, and may mess up other functionality but it works for me.